# File not found in pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to save my Machine learning mode using pickle

using this code

```
picklepath='project_folder/cache/'
def get_model():
    try:
        foo = pickle.load(open(picklepath+'f_path.pkl', "rb"))
        return foo
    except (OSError, IOError) as e:
        model=Model("model")
        pickle.dump(model, open(picklepath+'f_path.pkl', "wb"))
        return model

model = get_model()
```

on running my application getting this error :

```
pickle.dump(model, open(picklepath+'f_path.pkl', "wb"))\r: C:/...../example/index.py
[Fri Dec 10 11:41:07.530565 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 3728:tid 1188] [client ::1:49914] AH01215: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '
```

Any solution, Thanks

Comment: what are you using for ML model keras or tensorflow?

Comment: Does the folder you want to write the file exist?

Comment: Did you check that `picklepath` is what you expect it to be, and that `picklepath+'f_path.pkl'` computes a reasonable filename? Did you verify that your program is permitted to open a file with that path and name?

Comment: If you `open()` a file, you need to `close()` it afterwards. It's easier to do it using a `with` context.

Comment: @np8: Yes file exists

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Keras for ML model, Instead of using pickle directly why not use the Keras built-in model loading and saving functions

```
model = Sequential()
#model initializeation, layers and compiling goes here

#saving the weights of model
model.save_weights("project_folder/cache/model.h5")

#later when you want it just initialize empty model as usual
model = Sequential()
#your layers defination goes here
model.load_weights("project_folder/cache/model.h5")
```

If you want to skip the model creation and layers defining each time you can save it's structure in the form of json

```
with open("project_folder/cache/model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model.to_json())

#and later to load model structure
from keras.models import model_from_json
json_file = open('project_folder/cache/model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i'm using vosk api Reference: https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api it is working but the model is loading ever time and taking around 30s will your solution resolve this issue, i don't want to create seperate instance for model

Comment: i don't think so that if saving a model is taking time it has somthing to do with the way we are saving the structure and complexity of  model directly influence this, how much complex your model is? e.g. number of layers

Comment: Model files are approx 2.5 GB reference : https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models each time when i run my application it loads the model  return Model("model") is there any way that first time i run application it loads the model and further it users the same instance, i tried #model = Model("model")
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128) also but still same issue

Comment: Yes you can load your model one time, and keep that model behind a flask or django service that way you will only need to load int once and then always using  REST api provide input to model and teake results

Comment: Can i try with your solution ?

Comment: Yea flask is the quicker way to get it up  .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240000/discussion-between-zain-ul-abidin-and-user3653474).